# PHP database connection not displaying

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I created a db connection and now I am trying print_r the results just to get started....I do not know what I am doing wrong here below...

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "UserName", "Password", "Database");

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Table");

print_r($result);
```

but I get returned is this

```
mysqli_result Object ( )
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

That's how it works - query returns a resource object. To view the results, you can do something like this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    print_r($row);
}
```

You have a nice article about MySQLi [here](http://codular.com/php-mysqli).

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to "print" a resource.

You still need to fetch the result, e.g., `mysql_fetch_array()`, `$result->fetch_row()` etc.